# Cast to pointer from integer of different size in performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone

Tags: iphone

I have:

```
 BOOL someBoolValue = ... //some code returning BOOL
```

when I try to invoke:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshView:) withObject:someBoolValue waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I'm getting a warning:

> cast to pointer from integer of different size

Any hints on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a "raw" boolean value, where an `id` (pointer to an object) should be.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(refreshView:) 
      withObject:someBoolValue 
      waitUntilDone:NO]
```

should better be

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshView:) 
      withObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: someBoolValue] 
      waitUntilDone: NO]
```

You can extract the boolean value in your `refreshView:` method by sending the `boolValue` method to the number object:

```
if( [myWrappedBoolean boolValue] ) {
    ...
}
```

Unlike Java or C#, Objective-C has no "autoboxing" from primitive values to objects. The `BOOL` type is just a small integer type, which causes the error message you are seeing, because the compiler needs a pointer for the second argument to `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Now I get it.
I've got one more related question: what parameter type should I put to the refreshView: method? should it be BOOL? or id?

Comment: Definetly `id` or even a more specific type (`NSNumber` if you follow the direction given in the answer). No autoboxing also means no auto*un*boxing.